# Problema para la creacion de un proyecto en angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

Al momento de crear un proyecto en angular 8 me aparece el siguiente mensaje:
[image]

Package.json

[[image: 2]

Al momento de instalar los paquetes o independencias que requiere me marca error y al final dice que que los paquetes no se instalaron, podrían decir como arreglarlo, según me dicen es por que no se instalo bien angular, pero ya lo desinstale y volví a instalarlo pero el problema perciste

Comment: Tu pregunta necesita que incluyas el package.json de la aplicación. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: La version 8 de angular ya no se mantiene. Al instalar una version reciente de angular/cli debes tener por lo menos node v.12.x.x y npm >6.x.x que ya no son compatibles (y sin soporte) con angular 8. Si quieres utilizar un proyecto de angular 8 debes asegurarte de instalar  @angular/cli@8.x.x, node 12.x.x y npm 6.x.x. Lo cual te causara a su vez conflictos con los paquetes que tengas actualizados. En mi opinión, debes migrar, versión por versión, angular hasta la version 11 mínimo desde https://update.aungular.io

Comment: **Tienes una dependencia rota**, podrías intentar haciendo `npm update` o `ng update`, pero te dará más problemas y tendrás que tener mucha paciencia. Para poder darte más detalles tendrías que subir el archivo package.json (esta en la raíz del proyecto).

Answer (score 1):

El problema que te muestra está en los paquetes que se usan solo para desarrollo (`devDependecies`).

Por poner en contexto, las versiones están divididas en 3 partes, separadas por puntos. Por poner un ejemplo, si un paquete está en la versión 8.3.29, significa que está en la versión principal 8, en la subversión 3, y parche 29 de esa subversión.

Por otro lado, en el archivo `package.json` suele aparecer algún símbolo antes del número de versión (`~`, `^`, etc). Estos símbolos avisan de hasta qué versión se puede poner en el proyecto. El símbolo `~` dice que se instale el mayor parche sin cambiar de versión ni subversión. El símbolo `^` que se instale la mayor subversión sin cambiar de versión principal. En [este enlace](https://nodejs.dev/learn/semantic-versioning-using-npm) (en inglés) explica muy bien cada uno de los diferentes valores que pueden tener.

Para entender el error que te muestra por pantalla, en la línea `karma-jasmine-html-reporter: "^1.4.0",` está diciendo que se instale la mayor versión sin cambiar la principal. [Si miras en npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter) sería la versión 1.7.0, que en este caso coincide con su última versión. El problema viene que para poner esta versión necesita la versión 3.8 o superior del paquete `jasmine-core`, y si miras en tu `package.json` le está diciendo `jasmine-core: "~3.4.0",`, por lo que lo máximo que puede poner es la versión 3.4.9 (si existiera, que no lo he mirado).

**Solución fácil a tu problema**. Por como está el archivo, me inclino a pensar que lo más fácil sería cambiar la línea `karma-jasmine-html-reporter: "^1.4.0",` por `karma-jasmine-html-reporter: "~1.4.0",` y comprobar si así te crea el proyecto o si te da algún problema nuevo de dependencias. Y si esto ocurre, ir poco a poco ajustando, teniendo en cuenta que al no estar trabajando con las últimas versiones de los paquetes (cosa poco recomendable) no va a ser tan fácil como decir "ponme la versión más reciente de este paquete".

**Solución idónea a tu problema**. Como recomendación, como ya te han dicho en algún comentario, **deberías de trabajar con las últimas versiones de los paquetes**. Con esto ganarás tener toda la funcionalidad y solucionar problemas de seguridad, algunos de ellos críticos. Si empiezas un proyecto de nuevas será fácil, si es un proyecto antiguo es algo más complicado, pero con paciencia se consigue.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.